# Filter object with Vue.js, Axios and Django

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

I have a project with Vue.js and Django. I am trying to get a list from a database, with a simple search. In Vue/Axios, I have it:

```
  var food = 'CHICKEN'
  const url = `${API_URL}/api/list_food_composition/${food}`;
  axios.get(url).then(response => {
  var data = response.data;
  console.log(data)
  });
```

**But the response is 'undefined'**

In Django, I have it:

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/list_food_composition/$', views.list_food_composition),
```

views.py

```
def list_food_composition(request,food):
    foods = Food_composition.objects.filter(short_description__contains=food)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', foods)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

What is the correct way for do it?

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` give?

Comment: It is in bold. It response "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your view like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def list_food_composition(request,food):
     foods = Food_composition.objects.filter(short_description__contains=food)
     data = serializers.serialize('json', foods)
     return JsonResponse({'data': data}, content_type='application/json')
```

And the **URL**  should be:

```
url(r'^api/list_food_composition/(?P<food>\w+)$', views.list_food_composition),
```

Comment: You could have explained a bit instead of just posting code in my opinion.